# Using pscp With Remote Environment Variables

Tags: linux, environment-variables, pscp

I'm using `pscp.exe` to transfer files from Windows to Linux. This command works fine:

```
pscp myfile.txt user@host:/airflow/dags
```

The location on the Linux host into which I want to transfer the files is stored in a environment variable:

```
$ echo $AIRFLOW_HOME
/airflow
```

I'd like to refer to that environment variable in the call to `pscp`. Unfortunately it doesn't work:

```
pscp myfile.txt user@host:$AIRFLOW_HOME/dags
```

returns `pscp: unable to open /dags: permission denied` (which makes sense of course, `/dags` does not exist).

Clearly the `$AIRFLOW_DAGS` part of the command is not getting resolved on the host. So, is there a way to refer to environment variables on the host in my `pscp` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The utility `pscp` cannot resolve remote shell variables.  As a workaround, retrieve the value of a variable first over ssh (using the PuTTY command `plink`) and store it in a Windows variable.

Place the following commands into a batch file and run it.

```
@echo off 
for /f %%i in ('plink -ssh user@host echo $AIRFLOW_HOME') do set HOMEVAR=%%i
pscp myfile.txt user@host:%HOMEVAR%/dags
```

Note: To use the `for /f...` command from the command line (outside of a batch file), replace both `%%i` with `%i`.

Comment: Nice, thanks. I'm actually using PowerShell but I'm sure I can adapt it. Much appreciated.